Using geographical coordinates, given an arbitrary point, how to find the closest existing point on a linestring?
I'm working with shapely and django-gis. I'm given a linestring with full coordinates and a point with rounded to 6 coordinates.
What I need is to find the index of the nearest existing point from my linestring from the given arbitrary point, the nearest point on the linestring and add at index + 1 the coordinates of the the nearest point on the linestring.
My code is like below. However for some points it's raising a ValueError because closest point is not in linestring.
Example of succesfull data :
input : (4.756696, 45.381095)
output : (4.75669614409327, 45.3810948660022)
Example of failing data :
input : (4.756614, 45.380532)
output (4.756613683262075, 45.38053204640647) # this point is not inside the given linestring.
class SomeClass:
    @staticmethod
    def closest_point_on_linestring(line_coords: list, point: Point):
        line = LineString(line_coords)
        min_dist = float('inf')
        closest_point = None

        for idx in range(len(line_coords) - 1):
            segment_start = line_coords[idx]
            segment_end = line_coords[idx + 1]
            segment = LineString([segment_start, segment_end])

            # Project the point onto the segment
            projected_point = segment.interpolate(segment.project(point))

            # Calculate the distance from the point to the segment
            distance = projected_point.distance(point)

            # Calculate the distance between the segment's start and end points
            segment_length = Point(segment_start).distance(Point(segment_end))

            # Check if the distance to the segment is within the segment length
            if 0 <= segment.project(projected_point) <= segment_length:
                if distance < min_dist:
                    min_dist = distance
                    closest_point = projected_point

        return closest_point

   def another_function(self):
       ...
       closest = self.closest_point_on_linestring(line, Point(landmark_point))
       index = list(line_string.coords).index(closest.coords[0])
       ...

Below is a terrible drawing of my requirements :
The black line represents my linestring, the red dots the points of this linestring and the green dots the arbitrary points I'm given. I need to find the closest red dots for each green dots and the closest point inside the linestring (the interpolation is represented with blue lines).


The blue lines in your drawing are exactly horizontal. Is that the objective or should it be to a point on black curve closest to the green dots?

No it's not the objective, it's an approximation, it should be a point on black curve closest to the green dots.

You can use a tree to find the nearest existing points, and shapely.ops.nearest_points for point on the linestring.
import numpy as np
import shapely
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
from shapely import plotting, Point

curve = list(zip(np.linspace(0, 6, 25), np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 25))))

linestring = shapely.LineString(curve)

tree = KDTree(np.array(linestring.coords))
p = [4.5, 1.8]
_, index = tree.query(p)

print(f"Nearest existing point: {curve[index]}")

_, nearest_new = nearest_points(Point(p), linestring)

print(f"Nearest existing point: {nearest_new}")

plotting.plot_line(linestring, color='black')
plotting.plot_points(Point(p), color='green')
plotting.plot_points(Point(curve[index]), color='red')
plotting.plot_points(Point(nearest_new), color='blue')
plt.savefig('example.jpg')



This seems enough to get the closest red dot on my drawing, but not to get the blue dots.

adapted the answer with the same colors as your drawing.

I was working with coordinates and my problem was mostly the fact that I used coordinates in 4326 SRID. Anyways, thanks for your help.

I was working with coordinates and my problem was mostly the fact that I used coordinates in 4326 SRID. Below is my working code using shapely.
def closest_point_on_linestring(self, linestring: LineString, point: Point) -> tuple[tuple[float]]:
    """
    Finds the closest point on the linestring to the given point
    and projects the point onto the linestring.
    """
    linestring = shapely.from_wkt(linestring.wkt)
    min_distance = float("inf")
    closest_point = None
    for coords in linestring.coords:
        line_point = Point(coords)
        dist = shapely.distance(line_point, point)
        if dist < min_distance:
            min_distance = dist
            closest_point = line_point
    projected_point = shapely.line_interpolate_point(
        linestring, shapely.distance(linestring, point)
    )
    projected_point = self.transform_point_srid(projected_point, 2154, 4326)
    closest_point = self.transform_point_srid(closest_point, 2154, 4326)

    return closest_point, projected_point

